# A word to describe "the presence of someone/something has little or no significance in a given situation"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

I am trying to use a single word/simple sentence to explain a situation where adding/not adding a part to a device won't make any difference to its functionality.

Comment: You have received several answers but context is necessary to decide which is best. Please can you provide a sample sentence that has a blank where the word/phrase should appear. Preferably say what the device is and make the scenario plausible. Thanks.

Comment: If it doesn't affect anything, it's ***irrelevant***.

Comment: As adjectives: **pointless** or more litterary **supererogatory**. As noun: **futility**  (the quality of having no useful result; uselessness).

Answer (score 5):

**Superfluous**

adjective
unnecessary, not providing additional benefit

Comment: Superfluous works for my context. Thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 1):

I think Youkay's suggestion "nugatory" is ok but it's a bit obscure - depends on your readership. It's also has a condemnatory tone, to me at least. "**Redundant**" perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

> **irrelevant** - adjective:
>
> Not connected with or relevant to something.
>
> <sup>[Source: [Oxford Dictionaries online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/irrelevant)]</sup>

Comment: Welcome to the site, @UsmanKazi!

Comment: I added a citation and a link to the source of the definition you quote in your answer. At this site, it's an excellent practice to find reliable support for an answer (as you have done here), but it's also important to include citations (and if possible, links) to language taken from elsewhere; as the answerer, you are responsible for providing such documentation, going forward. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inconsequential:

> Of no significance

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inconsequential

Answer (score 0):

### Nugatory

From the [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nugatory):

> Of no value or importance: ‘a nugatory and pointless observation’

Here's a software-related [example](http://www.infoq.com/articles/the-curse-of-the-change-control-mechanism):

> The process of analyzing the impact of change requests can take so long and be so extensive that it has a destabilizing effect on the main team: they are only too aware that their current work may be rendered **nugatory** following the approval of the change requests.

Answer (score 0):

*Superfluous* is good... unless you are adding a part to make something 'look better'. In that case your addition would be "*purely* ***aesthetic***".